# Anaconda -- conda create results in "Failed to create process"

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda onto my laptop and I am trying to install a conda environment called pydecal that uses python 3.5. I have tried this in CMD as well as in Anaconda Prompt. I did not enter Python when  Below is my code:

```
conda create --name pydecal python=3.5
```

I am getting a "Failed to create process." message every time I try to run the command. Anaconda installed fine in 64-bit. I am on a clean install of Windows 10. I have no other instances of Python on my computer whatsoever. I have tried running CMD and Anaconda Prompt as an administrator. I have restarted my laptop several times. Regardless, I run into the same problem. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it on the primary drive (C:)?

My `conda` did not work either. I have just uninstalled Anaconda3 which was formerly installed in a secondary drive (E: rather than C:).

After installing Anaconda3 on the primary drive (C:), `conda` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making this way:

1: Install Anaconda in a directory structure not containing spaces.
2: Modify system environments to not include %PATH% in the user section.
   I found that 'echo %PATH%' in a prompt resulted in the system defined paths, were shown twice.
3: Moved all paths containing %SYSTEMROOT% to the top search order. This was to assure the need to search obscure named paths was not searched by the 'activate' command.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Br Michael

Comment: "Modify system environments to not include %PATH% in the user section." - Could you clarify what you mean by that? Do you mean, make sure that entries in the user PATH variable are not present in the system PATH variable, and vice versa?

Comment: It has been a while since i solved it, so this is what i remember.
if the "%PATH%" was present in the user defined section, the same python path was present always. This would cause a failure.
Making sure the system paths is not present in the user section allowed anaconda to control the user specific path to python.
That way anaconda can override the python path on a user basis.
I hope this makes sense in contrast to what I found back in June.

Comment: This simply does not work at least not for conda.  Conda is installed in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.7.10-py37_0\Scripts but it does not execute. It has this exact error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

Opening the "Anaconda Prompt" Console Link that Anaconda creates in the start menu. As conda appeared to work fine there I copied the predefined envinronment variables for that prompt :

If you check the link, it executes this:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\tools\Anaconda3
```

and that file refers to `C:\tools\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat`

So finally the path is specified there as :

```
C:\tools\Anaconda3;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\tools\Anaconda3\bin;C:\tools\Anaconda3\condabin;
```

I added that to the Windows System Environment variables and it now works properly on git bash, and other shells.

Answer (score 0):

pip install pathlib

that is what i did now everything works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).